# Old PC/laptop dismantling

Tags: thermal-paste, recycling

My husband and I have been dismantling old PCs and laptops for recycling. Inside most is some type of whitish silver powdery putty that holds processor chips securely and other things. It's almost like the graphite stuff for pinewood derby cars but thicker and more putty like.

What is it? Is it toxic?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Could the putty stuff be [thermal paste](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_paste)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the gum like thing on the heat sink?](https://superuser.com/questions/613658/what-is-the-gum-like-thing-on-the-heat-sink)

Answer (score 1):

#### Inside most is some type of whitish silver powdery putty

That is Thermal Paste:

> Thermal paste consists of a polymerizable liquid matrix and large volume fractions of electrically insulating, but thermally conductive filler. Typical matrix materials are epoxies, silicones (Silicone grease), urethanes, and acrylates; solvent-based systems, hot-melt adhesives, and pressure-sensitive adhesive tapes are also available. Aluminum oxide, boron nitride, zinc oxide, and increasingly aluminum nitride are used as fillers for these types of adhesives. The filler loading can be as high as 70–80% by mass,

...

> The most effective (and most expensive) pastes consist almost entirely of liquid metal, usually a variation of the alloy galinstan

Source: [Thermal paste - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_paste#Composition)

---

#### Is it toxic?

Here is part of the the Safety Data sheet for Arctic Silver (a commonly used thermal paste):

> - **Hazard statements**
>
>   Causes eye irritation.
>
>   Toxic to aquatic life with long lasting effects.
> - **Precautionary  statements**
>
>   Avoid release to the environment.
>
>   Wash thoroughly after handling.
>
>   If in eyes: Rinse cautiously with water for several minutes. Remove
>   contact lenses, if present and easy to do.
>
>   Continue rinsing.
>
>   If eye irritation persists: Get medical advice/attention.
>
>   Collect spillage.
>
>   Dispose of contents/container in accordance with
>   local/regional/national/international regulations.
> - **Unknown acute toxicity**:
>
>   10 percent of the mixture consists of ingredient(s) of unknown
>   toxicity

Source: [AS5_SDS.pdf](http://www.arcticsilver.com/PDF/AS5_SDS.pdf)

---

#### How can I remove it?

> Remove any thermal pads or other interface material from the heatsink.
>
> ...
>
> Thermal pads can be scraped off with a plastic tool that will not
> scratch the heatsink then the remnants can be removed with a xylene
> based cleaner, (Goof Off and some carburetor cleaners) acetone,
> mineral spirits, or 99% isopropyl alcohol.
>
> Never use any oil or petroleum based cleaners (WD-40, citrus based
> cleaners and many automotive degreasers) on  the base of a heatsink.

Source: [Microsoft Word - Thermal Compound Instructions2.doc - Compound Instructions.pdf](http://www.arcticsilver.com/PDF/Compound%20Instructions.pdf)

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that isopropyl 99% is typically the best solvent to use to remove it.  I would just double check to make sure there aren't exceptional cases.